# When are the constructors of an inductive type exhaustive?

Tags: coq

For a simple inductive type like the natural numbers `nat`, it is easy to prove that the two constructors (zero and successor) give all possible natural numbers,

```
Lemma nat_destruct (n : nat) : n = O \/ exists m : nat, n = S m.
Proof.
  destruct n. left. reflexivity. right. exists n. reflexivity.
Qed.
```

However I hear it is not so simple for equality proofs. There is only one equality constructor, `eq_refl`, but Coq cannot prove that

```
eq_destruct : forall (A : Type) (x : A) (prEq : x = x), prEq = eq_refl
```

What exactly blocks this proof ? Probably a first problem is that equality is not just a type, but a type family `eq : forall A : Type, A -> A -> Prop`. Is there a simpler type family where such a proof is impossible ? With 1 or 2 arguments instead of 3 maybe ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote about this issue in a [blog post](http://poleiro.info/posts/2018-01-26-equality-in-coq.html).  In general, this arises when you define a type family over a type that does not have decidable equality.  For example, consider the following type:

```
Inductive foo : Type -> Type :=
| Foo : foo unit.
```

It is not possible to show (I am pretty sure) that every inhabitant of `foo unit` is of the form `Foo`.

This phenomenon is easier to see at the level of proof terms.  When you destruct a term of such a family, you must generalize over the index of the family.  You can only relate this index to a known shape such as `unit` if the type has decidable equality.

Comment: Interestingly though, univalence implies that every `foo unit` is `Foo`.

Comment: @AndrásKovács Is this because `unit` is contractible? Would it fail if I replaced `unit` by `bool`?

Comment: Yes, to both questions.